# node_delete not working

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to delete some CCK nodes in Drupal using a standalone PHP script while logged in as anonymous user

```
if(empty($total_deals_for_this_pl)){
$node_nid = $single_result['nid'];
global $user;
$original_user = $user;
$user = user_load(1);
print $node_nid."<br>";
node_delete($node_nid);
$user = $original_user;
}
```

I am able to retrieve all the nid's successfully but the nodes are not getting deleted. I am loading Drupal as follows

```
chdir('C:\wamp\www\mysite\platform'); //my drupal resides here
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
include_once './includes/common.inc';
```

Comment: Note that this is not a safe way to impersonate a user.  Instead, use the function session_save_session().  See [Safely Impersonating Another User](https://drupal.org/node/218104).

Answer (score 3):

[`Node_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete/6) has an access check for delete permissions inside it.

Test again with anonymous users given permission to delete nodes.

Also try adding

```
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
```

If that doesn't work you could try up to the session phase:

```
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);
```

and finally the full dealio:

```
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Comment: i am loading admin before deleting so that should not be a problem. Still good point so i gave all permissions to all user including anonymous but still not working.

Comment: one little addition just added

Answer (score 2):

Three options:

1. Generally, I would recommend using [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) for this kind of thing. Its a more robust solution than a custom script. It's pretty easy to set up and once you've used it you'll probably think of a dozen other ways to use it.
2. Failing that, make your own module and stick your custom script inside a proper hook. Your custom script on its own might not be playing along with what other modules are expecting.
3. If you still want to have your own separate script I suspect it's the bootstrap code that's failing. Check out [drupal_bootstrap](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/6) for the options available to you.